# BasicTextField / TextField - How to remove padding to the left of leadingIcon?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a BasicTextfield working perfectly, the only thing I still need to do is to remove the padding to the left of the leadingIcon (and right of trailingIcon).

What it looks like currently :

[image]

Comment: Share a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: just add some custom offset to Icons ,for eg, -> `leadingIcon = { Icon(Icons.Default.Person, contentDescription = null,modifier = Modifier.offset(-8.dp)) },`

if you need more detailed answer, comment below and update your code in the question,  and tag me,i'll help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So...
Thank you @praveen-kumar, I tried your solution, and the icon was correctly offset to the left border of the BasicTextField, the problem, however, was that the label + padding were still in the same place, and I can't specify a PaddingValues with negative values.

The solution I ended with, which works perfectly, is to have a Box with the BasicTextField (with leadingIcon = null) + Icon as its direct children.
When I have to show the leadingIcon, I show the icon with a start and end padding, and the BasicTextField's DecorationBox's paddingValues to start padding + icon width + end padding

When I don't show the leadingIcon, I specify the paddingValues of the BasicTextField's DecorationBox as just the end padding.

Here is the full code, you can see the sections where I define the textPaddingStart val, the 24 refers to the icon's width, and the GYTheme.xxx.yyy are tokens (values) specific to my Design System :

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun Default(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    inputState: InputFieldState = InputFieldState.DEFAULT,
    inputType: InputFieldType = InputFieldType.Text,
    inputFormat: InputFieldFormat = InputFieldFormat.TEXT,
    label: String = "",
    placeHolder: String = "",
    value: String = "",
    isEnabled: Boolean = true,
    onValueChange: (String) -> Unit = {},
    onFocusChanged: ((Boolean) -> Unit)? = null,
    @DrawableRes leadingIcon: Int? = null,
    @DrawableRes trailingIcon: Int? = null,
    supportingText: String? = null,
    characterCountVisibility: Boolean = false,
    characterLimit: Int? = null,
    prefix: String? = null,
    suffix: String? = null,
) {

    val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
    val isPressed by interactionSource.collectIsPressedAsState()
    val isHovered by interactionSource.collectIsHoveredAsState()
    var isActive by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val resources = InputFieldResources.resources(
        state = inputState,
        isEnabled = isEnabled,
        isActive = isActive,
        isPressed = isPressed,
        isHovered = isHovered,
    )

    val shape = RoundedCornerShape(
        topStart = GYTheme.borderRadiusAlias.borderRadiusSymetricTopField.dp,
        topEnd = GYTheme.borderRadiusAlias.borderRadiusSymetricTopField.dp,
        bottomStart = GYTheme.borderRadiusAlias.borderRadiusSymetricBottomField.dp,
        bottomEnd = GYTheme.borderRadiusAlias.borderRadiusSymetricBottomField.dp,
    )

    val textPaddingStart = leadingIcon?.let {
        GYTheme.spacingAlias.spacePaddingHorizontalField + GYTheme.spacingAlias.spaceStackHorizontalField + 24
    } ?: GYTheme.spacingAlias.spaceStackHorizontalField

    val textPaddingEnd = leadingIcon?.let {
        GYTheme.spacingAlias.spacePaddingHorizontalField + GYTheme.spacingAlias.spaceStackHorizontalField + 24
    } ?: GYTheme.spacingAlias.spaceStackHorizontalField

    Column {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(top = GYTheme.spacing.space200.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth(),
        ) {

            BasicTextField(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .border(
                        border = BorderStroke(
                            width = resources.borderWidth.dp,
                            color = resources.borderColor,
                        ),
                        shape = shape,
                    )
                    .onFocusChanged {
                        onFocusChanged?.invoke(it.isFocused)
                        isActive = it.isFocused
                    },
                value = value,
                textStyle = GYTheme.typographyAlias.fontStyleFieldValue,
                onValueChange = onValueChange,
                enabled = isEnabled,
                interactionSource = interactionSource,
                readOnly = inputType.readOnly,
                maxLines = inputType.maxLines,
                decorationBox = @Composable { innerTextField ->
                    TextFieldDefaults.DecorationBox(
                        value = value,
                        visualTransformation = VisualTransformation.None,
                        innerTextField = innerTextField,
                        contentPadding = PaddingValues(
                            start = textPaddingStart.dp,
                            end = textPaddingEnd.dp,
                            top = GYTheme.spacing.space100.dp,
                            bottom = GYTheme.spacing.space100.dp,
                        ),
                        placeholder = {
                            Text(
                                text = placeHolder,
                                color = resources.placeholderColor,
                                style = GYTheme.typographyAlias.fontStyleFieldPlaceholder,
                            )
                        },
                        label = {
                            Column {
                                Text(
                                    modifier = Modifier,
                                    text = label,
                                    color = resources.labelColor,
                                    style = GYTheme.typographyAlias.fontStyleFieldLabel,
                                )
                                Spacer(
                                    modifier = Modifier.height(GYTheme.spacingAlias.spaceStackVerticalFieldLabelValue.dp)
                                )
                            }
                        },
                        prefix = prefix?.let {
                            {
                                Text(
                                    text = it,
                                    color = resources.prefixSuffixColor,
                                    style = GYTheme.typographyAlias.fontStyleFieldPrefixSuffix,
                                )
                            }
                        },
                        suffix = suffix?.let {
                            {
                                Text(
                                    text = it,
                                    color = resources.prefixSuffixColor,
                                    style = GYTheme.typographyAlias.fontStyleFieldPrefixSuffix,
                                )
                            }
                        },
                        shape = shape,
                        singleLine = false,
                        enabled = isEnabled,
                        interactionSource = interactionSource,
                        colors = buildColors(resources),
                    )
                }
            )

            leadingIcon?.let {
                Icon(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(start = GYTheme.spacingAlias.spacePaddingHorizontalField.dp)
                        .requiredSize(24.dp)
                        .align(Alignment.CenterStart),
                    painter = painterResource(id = it),
                    contentDescription = null,
                    tint = resources.leadingIconColor,
                )
            }

            trailingIcon?.let {
                Icon(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(end = GYTheme.spacingAlias.spacePaddingHorizontalField.dp)
                        .requiredSize(24.dp)
                        .align(Alignment.CenterEnd),
                    painter = painterResource(id = it),
                    contentDescription = null,
                    tint = resources.trailingIconColor,
                )
            }
        }

        InputFieldSupportingText(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(top = GYTheme.spacingAlias.spaceStackVerticalFieldContainerSupportingText.dp)
                .padding(horizontal = GYTheme.spacingAlias.spacePaddingHorizontalField.dp),
            resources = resources,
            supportingText = supportingText,
            characterCountVisibility = characterCountVisibility,
            characterCount = value.length,
            characterLimit = characterLimit,
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have specific code for your text field, please send it. I had a code, you may try it and tell if it solve your problem.

```
package com.example.stackquestions

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.material.Icon
import androidx.compose.material.IconButton
import androidx.compose.material.OutlinedTextField
import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.Clear
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.Person
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import com.example.stackquestions.ui.theme.StackQuestionsTheme

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            StackQuestionsTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
                        BasicTextField()

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun BasicTextField() {
    var text by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

    OutlinedTextField(
        value = text,
        onValueChange = { newText -> text = newText },
        label = { Text("Username") },
        leadingIcon = { Icon(Icons.Default.Person, contentDescription = null) },
        trailingIcon = {
            if (text.isNotEmpty()) {
                IconButton(onClick = { text = "" }) {
                    Icon(Icons.Default.Clear, contentDescription = null)
                }
            }
        },
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()

    )
}
```

Comment: The question asked for a `BasicTextfield` not an `OutlinedTextField` and nothing in your code reduces the padding as was asked.